# Problem with 'already defined' in newenvironment

Tags: errors, environments, tabularx, dotfill

I have the following environment for using `\dotfill` in a `cases` environment

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{DotCases}[1]{%  
    {#1}
\@ifdefinable\@FunFill{\newdimen\@FunFill}
\settowidth\@FunFill{$#1\left\{ \right.\kern -\nulldelimiterspace$}
    \left\{%
    \tabcolsep \z@
    \def\arraystretch{1.2}
    \tabularx{\dimexpr \linewidth-\@FunFill-2pt \relax}%
                {>{$}r<{$}>{${}}X<{$}}%
}{%
    \endtabularx
    \right.%
    \kern -\nulldelimiterspace
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$
\begin{DotCases}{f(x) = }
& x   \dotfill \text{text}\\
& 1-x \dotfill \text{more text}
\end{DotCases}
$

$
\begin{DotCases}{f(x) = }
& x   \dotfill \text{text}\\
& 1-x \dotfill \text{more text}
\end{DotCases}
$

\end{document}
```

I have compiled solutions from various places, and I only partially understand what's going on. What I am trying is to keep everything within `linewidth` and thus subtracting the width of `#1` and the left bracket from the `\dotfill` command - well sort of, because I have to subtract around 2pt extra to ensure vertical alignment.

Writing a single `DotCases` environment works fine, but writing multiple `DotCases` gives the error `\@FunFill already defined`. Any suggestions for how to solve this?

Comment: don't post disconnected fragments that are hard to debug, post a small complete document that shows the error. but ever do `\newdimen\@FunFill}` inside a document environment, you do not want to allocate a new register each time, just do this once ehen the macros are defined.

Comment: I have edited the post to only include one complete code fragment. Thanks for pointing it out.
I am not sure how to implement your suggestion, can you please elaborate, preferably with the complete code snippet? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never allocate registers in document environments, they are a fixed resource you just want to allocate them once, as the code is loaded.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter

\newdimen\@FunFill

\newenvironment{DotCases}[1]{%  
    {#1}%%%%%%
\settowidth\@FunFill{$#1\left\{ \right.\kern -\nulldelimiterspace$}%%%%%%%
    \left\{%
    \tabcolsep \z@
    \def\arraystretch{1.2}
    \tabularx{\dimexpr \linewidth-\@FunFill-2pt \relax}%
                {>{$}r<{$}>{${}}X<{$}}%
}{%
    \endtabularx
    \right.%
    \kern -\nulldelimiterspace
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$
\begin{DotCases}{f(x) = }
& x   \dotfill \text{text}\\
& 1-x \dotfill \text{more text}
\end{DotCases}
$

$
\begin{DotCases}{f(x) = }
& x   \dotfill \text{text}\\
& 1-x \dotfill \text{more text}
\end{DotCases}
$

\end{document}
```